# How can I change the phpstorm custom constructor template?

Tags: templates, constructor, phpstorm

I'm using phpstorm `code > Generate... > constructor` to get:

```
function __construct()
{
}
```

But I want:

```
public function __construct()
{
}
```

How can I change the template? Can't find anything and I don't want to use live templates instead (I like the generate function).

Comment: This is an old question, but I just searched for this and stumbled upon this. The youtrack link @LazyOne has provided was updated yesterday to "Fixed" so I'm guessing it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Should be available as template in 9.0. Until then you have to add it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I change the template?

You cannot. There is no template for constructor unfortunately.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16548

Follow this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by opening the preferences window. In there you'll find "File and Code Templates". On the code tab you can adjust all templates.

[image]